# moved git working copy, changes no longer detected

Tags: git

So I had uncommitted changes in my working copy. I ran out of disk space so I moved the working copy to another volume. Now git does not recognize that there are changes to be committed. Not sure how I should solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking I can just branch and push but would like to hear from someone more versed in git voodoo.

Comment: If there are no local changes then there is nothing to commit and nothing to push.

Comment: I suspect you did not move the clone completely. Maybe you forgot some hidden files?

Comment: That's quite possible. I just drug the project folder to a new drive and now that you mention I did get the "some file names are too long error"
Still, I'd like to make sure the repo gets the latest from my comp.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Let's have a small summary of what comes into mind after with the little information we have:

*If* you really corrupted the clone by copying only part of it (why ever), then it is corrupted, there is no magic voodoo button that can solve such data loss. But I doubt that is the issue here, your description does not fit, in such case one would expect git to complain about or at least point out missing or changed files. If I get your remarks right, then git instead simply does not show any local modifications, so claims there are none.

Second, if really somehow git lost control over some files which indeed have local modifications (whatever that really means...), then there is one thing your could try to recover at least part of the changes: make a second clone of the repository from some other location that is up to date (remember: in git there is not "server" acting as central repository, there are only clones at eye level). Now copy over the files from your supposedly broken clone to the fresh one, but _only those files under git control, so source files, images and the like. In case there are differences the new git clone should now show local modifications. You can achieve the same insight by simply using a `diff` tool to compare both clones files. But again: I doubt this is your issue.

Instead I have the impression you did not really lose anything, but are simply unaware of the situation. Two possible aspects come to mind:

1. maybe you accidentally switched to another branch right before, during or after the move? in that case you are now being shown the state of that branch, not the one before. If you then switch back the former branch you would see your modifications again.
2. and this actually is my guess what happened here: all is fine, your had local modifications and committed them, but you did not push them to some other repository. in that case git does indeed not show any local modifications, there are none. *But* your clone has a different log (history) in that case: it shows commits that exist locally, but not in other clones (repositories). In that case all you have to do is push those commits!

If I read between the lines I'd say you have been using a centralized revision control system like Subversion or CVS before, since you are using their terminology ("working copy"). git differs from those, it has different concepts that are indeed confusing at first when switching over. I was confused myself ;-) But gits approach does make a lot of sense. It offers a whole lot more of possibilities, features, flexibility and robustness. So investing into the switch is well worth it in my eyes.

So, what *is* your situation? Check your branches, the commit log and compare it with other clones (repositories). I hope it is one of the last two aspects I described. Cause in that case you made everything right, nothing is lost and the sun smiles at you today :-)

Comment: I never said I lost anything. My clone is fully functional. Before I moved these files git status notated that there were changes to be committed. Why I didn't take a second to commit and push those changes before I did this I'll never know. Probably why there's not much on google about it :)
Thanks for the detailed response just the same.

Comment: Sorry, I understood you lost your changes.